# What's the groovyx namespace?

Tags: groovy

**Question**

I'm a Groovy beginner and noticed that certain packages are in a namespace called `groovyx`. What's the notion behind `groovyx`?

**Examples**

For example, see the `import` statements here:

- [HTTP Builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder)
- [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html)

**Google**

Yes, I already googled. Didn't find the answer though. Searches:

- [What is the groovyx namespace?](https://www.google.ch/search?q=What%20is%20the%20groovyx%20namespace?)
- [groovyx package](https://www.google.ch/search?q=groovyx%20package)
- etc.

Comment: I always assumed it was simply an analogy with the `java.*`/`javax.*` division in the standard Java class library - things that are somehow less "core" than the `groovy.*` packages go into `groovyx.*` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a package name (denoting groovy extensions)

Several people writing extensions (or libraries) for groovy have chosen to put them in the `groovyx` package.

[Another example is GBench](https://github.com/gperfutils/gbench), the Groovy benchmarking utility